# Regex match String with + or - in between

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

My input is `1+1` or `1-1` or `2+9` or `3-12` or `31-10` or `11+11` and like wise

I tried

```
^\d*[\+\-]\d*$
```

It works but what I need is that the input like `+1` or `+2` or `+31` or `1+` or `7+` or `-1` or `-2` or `-31` or `1-` or `7-` should not match.

Comment: when you also want to match if there is an optioanl  whitespace between 1 and + ^\d+\s*[\+\-]\s*\d+$

Comment: if you change `*` to `+` and remove unnesesery `\` in `[]` your regex is corect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `*` with `+`:

```
var pat = @"^\d+[+-]\d+$";
```

See a [demo of how this regex works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cd%2B%5B%2B-%5D%5Cd%2B%5Cr%3F%24&i=1%2B1%0D%0A1-1%0D%0A2%2B9%0D%0A3-12%0D%0A31-10%0D%0A11%2B11%0D%0A%0D%0A%2B1%0D%0A%2B2%0D%0A%2B31%0D%0A1%2B%0D%0A7%2B%0D%0A-1%0D%0A-2%0D%0A-31%0D%0A1-%0D%0A7-&o=m).

The `+` quantifier will match *one* or more instances of a digit disallowing input like `-`, `+`, `1+` or `-2`.

Also, you need not escape `+` or `-` in the `[-+]` character class (`-` does not have to be escaped as it is at its start/end).

Here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/Ti4DBe):

```
var strs = new string[] {"1+1","1-1","2+9","3-12","31-10","11+11","+1","+2","+31","1+","7+","-1","-2","-31","1-","7-"};
foreach (string s in strs) 
{
    var matched = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d+[+-]\d+$");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s, matched);
}
```

Output:

```
1+1: True
1-1: True
2+9: True
3-12: True
31-10: True
11+11: True
+1: False
+2: False
+31: False
1+: False
7+: False
-1: False
-2: False
-31: False
1-: False
7-: False
```

Comment: If you need to also match standalone `-` and `+`, you will need to create an alternation group, like `@"^(?:\d+[+-]\d+|[-+])$"`. Though I doubt you need that.

Answer (score 0):

when you also want to match if there is an optional whitespace between 1 and +  u can use regex

```
^\d+\s*[+-]\s*\d+$
```

look for example at     https://regex101.com/r/bpCjKM/2

explanation regex

```
/
^\d+\s*[\+\-]\s*\d+$
/
g
^ asserts position at start of the string
\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character present in the list below [\+\-]
\+ matches the character + literally (case sensitive)
\- matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
\s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

Answer (score 0):

For you input try this one (i.e. Replace your regular expression's `*` to `+`)

`^\d+[\+\-]\d+$`

`*` denotes zero or more occurrences.

`+` denotes one or more occurrences.